# Why should i use ngModel twice?

Tags: html, angular

I have a code like this :

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" #email="ngModel" name="email" ngModel email required>
<p *ngIf="!email.valid && email.touched">Please type a valid email address!</p>
```

I understand why I used #email="ngModel" because in p element I reached that input but I dont understand why should I put single ngModel into input tag. I'm confused about this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#email="ngModel"` is just setting a reference from the current `ngModel` to `#email`.
`ngModel` as an attribute is a directive wich applies all ngModel logic to the element.

Simply said: Without the `ngModel` attribute you have nothing to reference for `#email`.